# WordPress category link

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am trying to create an online store from scratch, with categories and product pages.
Since is my first [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) store I'm stuck on this trivial problem which stopped me on my way.
The [permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) are set to Month and name just to know the settings.

I created several categories where I want to insert the future products.

The problem arise when I try to access a certain category link - `www.mysite.com/category/books/` - it displays the error page.

If I access `www.mysite.com/category/` it shows me the content of the category page created in the admin panel.

All I want to do is to display all books when the visitor clicks on `www.mysite.com/category/books/` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. Go to wp-admin/options-permalink.php and make your own settings: `/%category%/%postname%/`

And add a prefix on the field below: `category` or whatever you want

Read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for more options

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved it in another way, by modifying the category.php page.
There I inserted this code :

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$elms = explode('/', $uri) ;

$catName = $elms[4] ;
```

and it does the thing I need.

Comment: And when $elms doesn't have 5 items?